# What could be some ways to fake realtime global illumination from an emissive render texture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a movie theater with a video player screen, and since unity Enlighten support is heading out I'm trying to find an alternative. also this is for mobile vr headsets so full realtime gi isn't really the best option anyway.

This is what I have so far. But its very basic and since unity doesn't support realtime area lights the light doesn't really look like its from the screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScreenLight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Light[] sLights;
    public Material[] materials;
    public RenderTexture rt;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Remember currently active render texture
        RenderTexture currentActiveRT = RenderTexture.active;

        // Set the supplied RenderTexture as the active one
        RenderTexture.active = rt;

        // Create a new Texture2D and read the RenderTexture image into it
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(rt.width, rt.height);
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), 0, 0);

        // Restore previously active render texture
        RenderTexture.active = currentActiveRT;

        var texColors = tex.GetPixels32();
        var total = texColors.Length;
        var r = 0; var g = 0; var b = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            r += texColors[i].r;
            g += texColors[i].g;
            b += texColors[i].b;
        }

        // Gets average texture color
        Color averageColor = new Color32((byte)(r / total), (byte)(g / total), (byte)(b / total), 0);


        // Updates lights and materials to the average texture color
        foreach (Material mat in materials)
        {
            mat.SetColor("_EmissionColor", averageColor);
        }

        foreach (Light l in sLights)
        {
            l.color = averageColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Unity doesn't support realtime area lights` .. the [`Projector`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html) is kind of like one actually ;)

Comment: @derHugo I did try the projector, however I was using to try and display the render texture. It never occurred to me to use it as just a light source! That might actually work! Thanks!